# google static map api works on host only after localhost

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

i have Simple API Access key for my website..
I have set Referers:www.mysite.com and www.mysite.com/*..
i am using static map api in my website.ex: https://maps.google.com/staticmap?markers=11.6879216,92.7241781&size=300x300&**key=mykey**&sensor=false. .
when i am trying to access in page i got this message..
"The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This site or IP is not authorized to use this API key.".
But if load the same page with same api key in localhost using wamserver, it shows the map. .
**After that  it shows the map in website also if i load again**.
 
why is it happening like this?.
can anyone solve my problem.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just confirm that you are putting the URL into the src tag of an IMG element?

Make sure you have enabled the static API for your personal key on the API console page: https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply.This only works for address. But i need to use latitude,longitude.and yes i have put in right place. actually it works in localhost. But in website it works only after i query same from localhost.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, I just uploaded it to my server as well to give it a shot.  Did you enable the Static Map API on the API console?  I had to do that, and it is working now.

Comment: static map api is enabled. my problem is "website shows map after i load same latitude, longitude in localhost" (i have the same setup in my local machine).

Comment: Well, when you load it in localhost it is cacheing the picture, so your browser can then find the local copy instead of requesting the URL from the API.  There is a problem with the key you are using.

Comment: corrrect.when i clear the cache its not showing the map on website. Thanks for the clarification. can you please also tell me , what could be the problem with the API key. I created today.

Comment: Which key are you using?  When I went to get mine to test this code, I went to the site listed above and used the key under the "Simple API Access" in my account.

Comment: yes.i use the same key. and i have set Referers to :Any referer allowed. But it doesn't work. i selected 'on' in all services page.what other steps involved in this

Comment: i think it is solved. i used http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap? instead of  https://maps.google.com/staticmap?. now it is showing the map. thanks for the help