# Get users current location in JavaScript, via the GeoLocation API

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, google-maps

Actually I want to get user's current location to trace its movement, Is it possible in Asp.Net web app? Because i need to trace it after every second or continuously. I did a code which give me latitude and longitude at localhost but not on ip Address why? It give error on map "Something went wrong". Code is given below
Header section

```
 <head runat="server">
<title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function setText(val, e) {
     document.getElementById(e).value = val;
         }
    function insertText(val, e) {
document.getElementById(e).value += val;
  }

   var nav = null; 
 function requestPosition() {
    if (nav == null) {
  nav = window.navigator;
    }
   if (nav != null) {
  var geoloc = nav.geolocation;
  if (geoloc != null) {
      geoloc.getCurrentPosition(successCallback);
  }
  else {
      alert("geolocation not supported");
  }
 }
else {
  alert("Navigator not found");
   }
   }
 function successCallback(position)
  {
   setText(position.coords.latitude, "latitude");
   setText(position.coords.longitude, "longitude");
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
   position.coords.latitude);
   var myOptions = {
   zoom: 8,
         center: latlng,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker
    (
    {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
    position.coords.longitude),
    map: map,
    title: 'Click me'
    }
     );
     }
    </script>
    </head>
```

Now the body section is

```
     <body>
     <label for="latitude">Latitude: </label><input id="latitude" /> <br />
     <label for="longitude">Longitude: </label><input id="longitude" /> <br />
     <input type="button" onclick="requestPosition()" value="Get Latitude and Longitude"  /> 
      <div id="map" style="width:400px;height:400px">
            </div>

       </body>
```

Comment: This is JavaScript code, not C# and ASP.NET.

Comment: @krlzlx i edited tags. But can you guide me how to handle it?

Comment: Never done that but I guess it requires more than a few lines of code!

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla's MDN network has a very good example of a solution to your question:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

This works fine for me in JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/), but not in the StackOverflow code snippet below (at least in the latest version of Chrome).  This is likely a problem with cross origin policy regarding the GeoLocation API.

```js
function geoFindMe() {
  var output = document.getElementById("out");

  if (!navigator.geolocation){
    output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
    return;
  }

  function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=true";

    output.appendChild(img);
  }

  function error() {
    output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
  }

  output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating…</p>";

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color:#ffffc9
}

p { margin : 0; }
```

```html
<p><button onclick="geoFindMe()">Show my location</button></p>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Now my code also works fine  on localhost after adding GoogleApi Key, but when i move it to domain(Live) it doesn't work

Comment: This question seems to be very similar:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19740416/2147110